# CSS background property can not override IE filter property?

Tags: html, css

#### Hi..

I have a label whose background is gradient by default(IE ).

```
     label{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid red;
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorStr="#ff3333",endColorStr="#663300");
     }
<label> Rama Rao </label>
```

I am allowing user to change that background color either gradient or normal. I am getting the value that user has entered,and setting css:

```
<label style="background:#val1"> Rama Rao </label>
```

OR

```
  <label style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorStr="#val1",endColorStr="#val2");"> Rama Rao </label>
```

It works if user again sets gradient ...but not if user enter normal color...But as per my knowledge,an `inline-style` can override internal style.....But its not working in `filter` case *(I mean, a filter cannot be overridden by background)*...How can I overcome this?
**Note :** For name shake,I mentioned `<label>` here...But it may happen for any tag....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove it using this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
```

Also you can check this fiddle I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Ajs/).

And the code your are using for gradients is for Internet Explorer only. If you want code that is compatible for most browsers check this tool [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: Awesome fix! Thanks you  :) Long live the community! ^_^