# Css - Overriding Internet Explorer specific styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working on styling an e-commerce Gekosale. Unfortunately I cannot alter the existing css files (they are overwritten when user saves some settings in the admin area). Those existing css files contain IE specific styles ie.

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#063053', endColorstr='#395873');
```

I don't know how to alter them from my own file. I know how to alter every "normal" style

```
.class123
{
  color: red;
}
```

can be easily altered with:

```
.class123
{
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to turn off IE gradients and others alike from CSS?

Comment: Looks like what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243182/css-background-property-can-not-override-ie-filter-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false) !important;
```

should do the trick. You can also try :

```
filter: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

write this in your CSS -

```
*{ filter: none !important; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! One line completely fixes the whole layout in IE!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that in your head tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
    .your-class {
        filter: none;
         }
 </style>
```